# Href multiple images inside of an SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

So, I am trying to link three images that are all inside of the same SVG but they all have different links.

I tried wrapping this code:

```
<g id="Group_624" data-name="Group 624" transform="translate(-962 -1111.615)">
<rect id="TestEd_Logo_Inline" width="493.368" height="149.913" transform="translate(962 1111.615)" fill="url(#pattern)"/>
<rect id="linguaskill_logo" width="245" height="43" transform="translate(962 1315)" fill="url(#pattern-2)"/>
<rect id="cambridgelogoinline" width="219" height="37" transform="translate(1238 1318)" fill="url(#pattern-3)"/>
```

With this:

```
<a xlink:href="{link}"></a>
```

To no avail, I also tried wrapping each 'id' with the a tag to no avail either.

This is the code inside of the svg tag:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="495" height="246.385" viewBox="0 0 495 246.385">
```

Am I missing something? or is this not possible?

Comment: What images? There are none in your code.

Comment: The SVG contains three different sections of code that make up the three images, apologies for the confusion

Comment: You mean the patterns? I demo would be useful here.